# Is it possible to write a function inside a filter in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In a custom filter i have a lot of `"if` conditions, i would like to avoid to repeat my code if i have the choice.

I tried to create a function, but it seems don't want to work. Is it possible to create a function inside a filter ? If not, how can i call a function from a filter (if possible) ?

I tried to declare it like this :

- `$scope.mySearch = function(mySearch, searchArr, filled)` but, got an error message because of $scope.
- `function(mySearch, searchArr, filled)`, but how can i call it ?
- `mySearch : function(mySearch, searchArr, filled)`, got a warning message about the label mySearch.

```js
// I TRIED TO INJECT $SCOPE, BUT THE WAY I DID IT WASN'T PROBABLY GOOD : 

.filter('searchFilter', function($filter, $scope)

    .filter('searchFilter', function($filter)
    {
        return function(items, mySearch, searchArr)
        {

            if((mySearch === "") && (searchArr.name !== ''))
            {         
                var firstSearch = $filter('filter')(items, searchArr.name);
                var city = $scope.myTestFunc(mySearch.result, searchArr, firstSearch);
                return city;
            }


    // THE FUNCTION I WOULD LIKE TO CALL ABOVE

           $scope.myTestFunc = function(mySearch, searchArr, firstSearch)
           {
               // Do the job
           }

       };
});
```

```html
 <ion-item ng-repeat="result in results | searchFilter : mySearch.result : searchArr" class="item-avatar">
```

Comment: Try `() => {}` maybe that might work

Comment: Would you not just call it as a plain function? `var city = myTestFunc(...)` and `function myTestFunc(mySearch, searchArr, firstSearch)`

Answer (score 1):

```
var my_search = function(mySearch, searchArr, filled){};
//or
function my_search(mySearch, searchArr, filled){}
```

I'd prefer the first... Store an anonymous function into the variable.

Comment: I'd prefer second, which doesn't require the function definition to be on top of the code using it.